# Videosphere does not work on android browser

Tags: html, aframe

I add videosphere using aframe. But in android browser it does not work. I am using Samsung S6. In S6 I checked many examples along with my code. It does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame</title>
<meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame">
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var scene = document.querySelector("a-scene");
    var vid = document.getElementById("video");
    var videoShere = document.getElementById("videoShere");

    if (scene.hasLoaded) {
      run();
    } else {
      scene.addEventListener("loaded", run);
    }

    function run () {
      if(AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile()) {
        document.querySelector('#splash').style.display = 'flex';
        document.querySelector('#splash').addEventListener('click', function () {
          playVideo();
          this.style.display = 'none';
        })
      } else {
          playVideo();
      }
    }

    function playVideo () {
      vid.play();
      videoShere.components.material.material.map.image.play();
    }
  })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="splash" style="display:none;">
  <div id="start-button">Start</div>
</div>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
      <video id="video" src="https://ucarecdn.com/fadab25d-0b3a-45f7-8ef5-85318e92a261/" webkit-playsinline></video>
  </a-assets>

  <a-entity camera="userHeight: 1.6" look-controls cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"></a-entity>

  <a-videosphere id="videoShere" loop="true" src="#video" rotation="0 -90 0"></a-videosphere>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. What is the issue with my code? And why it does not work on android browser? Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the A-Frame docs (https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/primitives/a-videosphere.html#caveats), you should have the following lines in your code to ensure they function properly in as many devices as possible:

```
<head>
...
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
...
</head>
```

In the `<video>` element, itself, you will want to use this code to ensure that the video will play inline and will start playing immediately, if supported by the browser:

```
<video id="video" src="https://ucarecdn.com/fadab25d-0b3a-45f7-8ef5-85318e92a261/" autoplay loop playsinline webkit-playsinline crossorigin="anonymous"></video>
```

Note that `crossorigin="anonymous"` should be set when using assets hosted on other domains. It's also worth noting that some domains won't let you do this even if you use this code.

User interaction within the browser (outside of A-Frame) may be required to trigger the video for browsers that do not allow autoplaying by default. I modified your modal slightly to make it more visible:

```
<div id="splash" style="display: flex; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 999999; position: absolute; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);">
  <div id="start-button">Start</div>
</div>
```

The javascript can be simplified just by placing the following code immediately before the ending `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
// User interaction modal to trigger video in some browsers/devices.
var modal = document.querySelector('#splash');
var video = document.querySelector('#video');

modal.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  video.play();
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
});
</script>
```

Now, when a user clicks the modal splash screen, the event listener will capture the event, play the video, and remove the splash screen entirely from the DOM.

Here is a working demo: https://ultra-bass.glitch.me/

You just may need to add logic for detecting mobile devices, or more specifically, the devices that require this workaround.